# Django: How to filter my models (by child)?

Tags: python, django, filter

For my university project, I've described several models for e-commerce of goods:

`Item, Book(Item)`, `Stationery(Item)`, and `ItemImage` (related by ForeignKey for all Item-like models).

I need to filter the set of item images in the following way:

```
def home(request):
   goods_images = ItemImage.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_main=True)
   goods_images_books = ItemImage.objects.filter(is_active=True, 
                                                 is_main=True)
   goods_images_stationeries = ItemImage.objects.filter(is_active=True, 
                                                        is_main=True)
return render(request, 'landing/home.html', locals())
```

The question is what the additional parameter I should add to `filter()`? Or is there another way of solving this problem?

Comment: can you update your models

Comment: Yes, but without adding a new ForeignKey field.

Comment: without adding ForeignKey we can't do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Entry(models.Model):

    entry_title = models.ForeignKey(Title, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    some_other_field= models.CharField()

class Title(models.Model):
    pass

Title.objects.filter(entry__some_other_field = 'something')
```

Comment: ForeignKey returns only ID of the linked object, so I need this to be a string representation of object's class name.